# Avoiding sin stock: does it make a difference?

Tags: stocks, investing, ethical-investing

Until now I've avoided sin stock, such as tobacco, for the typical "moral reasons" (define those as you will), in particular in order to **avoid raising their value** as a company by creating demand (even if it is a drop in the ocean).

However, [this article](https://theconservativeincomeinvestor.com/if-you-find-tobacco-stocks-unethical-you-should-buy-tobacco-stocks/), in its second point argues:

> By refusing to buy a tobacco stock, you are theoretically lowering the price of the stock by decreasing the demand. If millions of Americans share your attitude, you can lower the price of the stock [...]

What happens then? Even if there were no hedge-fund that would buy the cheap stock, the article argues that **the company itself can engage in better-value-for-money stock buyback**.

So does it really matter to avoid (existing, already issued) sin stocks?

Edit:
It is different from "[Ethics and investment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/52313)" question as that one is discussed broad investment strategies with ethics, however mine is "how exactly do I support unethical business by trading their shares and does it have any real impact?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ethics and investment](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/ethics-and-investment)

Comment: @Grade-eh-bacon 's answer implies he believes the question is different from the linked one. My gut was to agree with Nathan, but give some time to see if there was a twist that was different enough to support this as a new question.

Comment: If anything, I think that my question overlaps more with "why would a company care about the price of its own shares": http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7800/why-would-a-company-care-about-the-price-of-its-own-shares-in-the-stock-market?noredirect=1&lq=1 (but I still see it different enough)

Comment: "Does it make a difference?" Maybe not to anyone in the world but your own self. If you can't force them out of business, is the only alternative to go ahead and collect your share of their profit? Or is there in fact a whole different reason to divest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, it does matter. You are right that lower demand for a stock will drive its price down. Lower stock prices can hurt the company. Take a look at Fixee's answer to [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7800/why-would-a-company-care-about-the-price-of-its-own-shares-in-the-stock-market):

> a declining share price will make it hard to secure credit, attract further investors, build partnerships, etc. Also, employees are often holding options or in a stock purchase plan, so a declining share price can severely dampen morale.
>
> In an extreme case, if share prices plummet too far, the company can be pressured to reverse-split the shares, and (eventually) take the company private. This recently happened to Playboy.

If you do not want to support a company, for whatever reason, then it is wise to avoid their stock.

Comment: I knew there was a catch! good answer!

Comment: @Andrey I'm glad you think so!  if this was helpful to you, then you may wish to upvote [Fixee's original answer](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/7802/45435)

Comment: Also note there's a good number of "Socially Responsible Mutual Funds" available these days that avoid things like alcohol, tobacco, poor working conditions (sweatshops), etc.

Comment: To be fair, _not_ buying a stock would not affect the share price in the slightest, but you are right that buying stock does support the company, but only marginally.

Comment: @DStanley It depends on your perspective. A share price is driven by supply and demand. From a global perspective, if all the demand dried up then the price would likewise decline

Comment: @DanielCarson Fair enough.  I was looking at it similarly to voting.  _Not_ voting for someone does not keep them from getting elected.  _Not_ buying a stock does not affect its share price, but buying it would raise it. Not a perfect analogy, and your point is valid.

Comment: @DStanley And conversely, from an individual's perspective, if I never hear of, buy, or sell a stock it's reasonable to think that I have no impact on it.

Comment: This is rather irrelevant to tobacco companies, which are shrinking high-cash flow companies. They want to buy back stocks anyway, and need to get rid of personnel. The problem with this answer is that it applies only to companies in a growth phase.

Comment: A declining share price is an *indicator* of the perceived health and future prospects of a company.  A prospective investor or debt buyer will analyze the company's finances to determine creditworthiness or likelihood of a prosperous investment or partnership.  Share price might weigh a little on some ratios but a falling share price does not necessarily create a harsher credit environment for the company.  Additionally, a falling share price may prove to attract investors.

Comment: Is this answer really correct? If there are some funds who don't care about ethics then they'll make a profit by buying the unethical stock, and in the process drive the stock back up.

Comment: @OscarCunningham It is extremely unlikely that everyone would decide to boycott a profitable company, especially since there are funds which exist solely to buy up "value stock"

Comment: @DanielCarson Exaclty. So doesn't that invalidate your answer? Refusing to buy a sin stock doesn't harm the company because other investors will anticipate your actions and act to cancel them out.

Comment: @OscarCunningham Except that the only thing you can be certain of is that nothing is certain. If you believe that a company is doing something morally wrong and you desire to stick to your convictions then it makes sense to avoid that stock no matter how unlikely it is that you will make a significant difference. It's like voting. It is extremely unlikely that your single vote will make a difference in an election, yet many people still vote.

Answer (score 5):

**This question drives at what value a shareholder actually provides to a corporation, and by extent, to the economy.**

If you subscribe for new shares (like in an Initial Public Offering), it is very straightforward to say "I have provided capital to the corporation, which it is using to advance its business." If you buy shares that already exist (like in a typical share purchase on a public exchange), your money doesn't go to the company. Instead, it goes to someone who paid someone who paid someone who paid someone (etc.) who originally contributed money to the corporation.

**In theory, the value of a share price does not directly impact the operation of the company itself**, apart from what @DanielCarson aptly noted (employee stock options are affected by share price, impacting morale, etc.). This is because in theory, the true value of a company (and thus, the value of a share) is the present value of all future cashflows (dividends + final liquidation). This means that in a technical sense, a company's share price should *result* from the company's value. The company's true value does not *result* from the share price.

**But what you *are* doing as a shareholder is impacting the liquidity available to *other* potential investors** (also as mentioned by @DanielCarson, in reference to the desirability for future financing). The more people who invest their money in the stock market, the more liquid those stocks become. This is the true value you add to the economy by investing in stocks - you add liquidity to the market, decreasing the risk of capital investment generally.

The fewer people there are who are willing to invest in a particular company, the harder it is for an investor to buy or sell shares at will. If it is difficult to sell shares in a company, the risk of holding shares in that company is higher, because you can't "cash out" as easily. This increased risk then does change the value of the shares - because even though the corporation's internal value is the same, the projected cashflows of the shares themselves now has a question mark around the ability to sell when desired.

Whether this actually has an impact on anything depends on how many people join you in your declaration of ethical investing. Like many other forms of social activism, success relies on joint effort. This goes beyond the direct and indirect impacts mentioned above; if 'ethical investing' becomes more pronounced, it may begin to stigmatize the  target companies (fewer people wanting to work for 'blacklist' corporations, fewer people buying their products, etc.).

Comment: Plot twist then: does it make "ethical sense" to buy & hold a sin stock (thus very passive as a liquidity provider) and then e.g. give away part of dividend to charity? Is it "better" than not buying at all?

Comment: @Andrey By buying a stock, you are adding liquidity to that stock, at a point in time. By committing to never buy it, you are reducing the pool of available investor capital for that company. By buying and holding it, you have still reduced that corporation's "need" for capital, by the amount that you are holding. Imagine a $1M company. You buy $100k of stock, meaning now the rest of the investing world only needs to cough up $900k to own it. You're left in a position where you profit off something you find unethical. It is the social aspect of blacklisting a company that has a bigger impact.

Comment: does this apply to ipo or to existing shares as well?

Comment: @Andrey It applies to existing shares as well. By buying and holding stock, you are reducing the need for additional liquidity for the other shareholders of that company. But again, the true benefit in such action is more in the promotion of social justice through visible means. Making your voice be heard, and standing up against what you find unethical, by refusing to profit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is, *"how exactly do I support unethical business by trading their shares and does it have any real impact?"*

By trading their shares, you're owning their shares. **By owning their shares, you're complicit in their activities**.

It's true that their are sin-stock activists who genuinely hope to force these businesses to change, but, many investors don't expect their refusal to participate in an exploitative, objectionable business to change anything but their own individual moral condition.

With that in mind, absolutely, yes, it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the premise of the article is a bit short sighted:

> 2. Most tobacco companies are currently engaging in stock buybacks, in particular Lorillard and Philip Morris International. By refusing to buy a tobacco stock, you are theoretically lowering the price of the stock by decreasing the demand.

Lower demand also means lower supply.  That affects liquidity if the volume traded daily is low but Philip Morris is a behemoth with a huge daily volume  so activists are going to have a minimal effect on its share price.  It's wishful thinking.

With stocks that truly have lower liquidity, spreads widen. However, a consequence of lower liquidity is that it's much easier to move share price and buybacks will certainly achieve that.

Not a good analysis in the linked article.